# Проблема с принятием POST запроса на Node + Express сервере

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

```
Node
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
})
app.post("/api/payment/qiwi", urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.query)
})


React:
fetch('http://domain.ru:4000/api/payment/qiwi/', {
        method: 'post',
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({payment: 'QIWI', value: 100, steamId: props.data.steamId}),
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
```

req.query - выводит json при запросе с Postman, но при отправке с сайта пусто, так же как и в req.body

Comment: Вас не смущает, что посылаете вы application/json, а получить пытаетесь application/x-www-form-encoded?

Comment: Спасибо, зафиксил